# How to make a query with PostgreSQL and TypeORM) where a Table has a JSON Type Column

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

How can I query from a JSON-type Column in PostgreSQL? Let's say following is my Entity witch contains the JSON-type column validDates:

```
// My Menu - Entity Class
@Entity()
export Class Menu {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
     id: string;
  @Column('json', {nullable: true})
    validDates?: ValidDatesClass;
}

// The ValidDatesClass
export class ValidDatesClass {
   [key: string]: boolean;
}
```

And I want to retrieve (SQL syntax) all Menus where validDates 's value is true (example of a validDates- entry: "Mon Aug 01 2018": true )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typeorm postgres select where json field equals some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808304/typeorm-postgres-select-where-json-field-equals-some-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
async getAllBrands() {
  return this.productsRepository
    .query(`SELECT properties->'brand' as brand from product`);
}
```

For more details:
https://wanago.io/2020/12/28/nestjs-json-postgresql-typeorm/