# TypeORM PostgreSQL select where JSON field equals some value

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

**Goal:**  write a select query that returns all rows where state equals "florida".

Entity column:

```
  @Column({ type: 'json'})
  public address: Address;
```

Sample column value:

```
{"city": "miami", "state": "florida"}
```

Example query (doesn't work):

```
getManager().getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .select()
    .where('user.address.state =:state', {state: "florida"})
```

Is this functionality currently supported in typeorm?  If so, how would I need to modify my where clause to return the correct rows?

Answer (score 19):

Another possible solution (raw SQL can not be injected with this):

```
.where('user.address ::jsonb @> :address', {
    address: {
        state: query.location
    }
})
```

With this, TypeORM will produce an SQL query ending with

```
WHERE user.address ::jsonb @> $1
```

and the query will be given e.g.

```
{ state: 'florida' }
```

as a query parameter to replace the right value ($1) in the query.

Sources: Mainly the original question + answer (thank you!) + own testing + https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

Comment: how to use  comparison operators? like this  . where('user.address ::jsonb @> :address', {
    address: {
        state: LessThan (query.pincode)
    }
})

Answer (score 16):

Got it working.

Correct syntax:

```
.where(`user.address ::jsonb @> \'{"state":"${query.location}"}\'`)
```

Comment: I should add to be aware of possible SQL injection when using the above syntax.  Properly sanitizing any incoming queries is a must.

Answer (score 9):

It works for me:

```
.getRepository(User)
.createQueryBuilder('user')
.where(`user.address->>'state' = :state`, {state: "florida"})
```

Answer (score 4):

More modern approach would be to use [JsonContains](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9665).

```js
import { JsonContains } from 'typeorm'

repo.find({
    where: { address: JsonContains({ state: 'florida' }) },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    return getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .where('address @> :address', {
      address: { state: "florida" },
    })
    .getMany();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   const users = await getManager()
  .getRepository(UserEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder(`user`)
  .where("address->>'state' = :state")
  .setParameters({ state })
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 1):

.where("user.address->>'state' = :state", {state: "florida"}).getMany();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nidovic, this doesn't work for camelcase, for example `user.myAddress` - gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
.where(`user.address -> '$.state' = :state`, {state: "florida"})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -6):

This works for me. I just use TypeORM like function.

```
.find({
   where: {
      address: Like(`%${add what to search for here}%`),
   },
});
```