# Typeorm query mysql json data column

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, typeorm

How would you execute this query with typeorm?

`SELECT * from t_integration_app WHERE settings = JSON_OBJECT("modelType", JSON_ARRAY("ACTION"));`

I tried something like:

```
repository.find({
    where: {
        settings: { modelType: "ACTION" }
    },
})
```

but it fails with this error message

`"errorMessage": "Unknown column 'modelType' in 'where clause'"`

Comment: I think you need to access those json objects differently, look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808304/typeorm-postgresql-select-where-json-field-equals-some-value and https://rahulthinking9.medium.com/how-to-query-jsonb-using-typeorm-and-postgresql-37ff7f1a3ea1

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
await repository
  .createQueryBuilder('t_integration_app')
  .where({ ...filter })
  .andWhere(
    `t_integration_app.settings = JSON_OBJECT("modelType", JSON_ARRAY(:modelType))`,
    { modelType: filterBy.modelType }
  )
  .getMany();
```